# Is it a good idea to add an continuous refreshing ListView inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview

I have a design which is covering ListView as a inner view inside four views. This ListView keeps on updating every milliseconds because we are displaying live data from BLE device. 
So, for that four views is it good idea to put into a RecyclerView with four rows or keep four different LinearLayouts. 
Please consider this question as speed of the application point of view.
Please refer below image for better understanding.

[image]

Comment: If it doesn't scroll, there's really no point in using a `RecyclerView` or a `ListView`.

Comment: Is it going to be there 4 items max? Will the items have a fixed height?

Comment: @HedShafran yes max 4 items and height will change as per no of items. So for that I can weight 1

Comment: So as @MikeM. said, No need for a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`. You can use `LinearLayout` and use `addView()` like methods... If there's a chance the content will be taller than the screen you can wrap it all in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @HedShafran you are right line of code will be more then RecyclerView but functionality wise it will be a better option to choose simple Layout method.